# UIView on existing view controller or another UIViewController and storyboards segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I wrote a simple quiz game and I need "Start Game" screen - just one UIButton. I can add UINavigationController and then make segue from second UIViewController or just another UIView with UIButton on top of an existing controller and hidden/unhidden it. Which way is better?

Comment: You should use a UINavigationController and then create a segue from the button to the next UIViewController. It will make your life easier in the long run (in my opinion). If you have a UINavigationController and later on decide to add several more UIViewController you will already have everything set up. This will also separate your code.

Comment: Thank You, I will try with segue. "Separate code", smart move, I'm reading about MVC but unfortunately my app is nothing like it so far.

Comment: No problem. Be sure to pick a design pattern as soon as possible though so you can save yourself from a headache or two down the road.